# Entity Framework Core 1.0 CurrentValues.SetValues() does not exist

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm attempting to update an entity and its related child entities using Entity Framework Core 1.0 RC 1, where the entities are detached from DbContext. I've done this previously using a solution similar to the one described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7969372/896265).

However, it seems that we are no longer able to do the following using Entity Framework 7:

```
DbContext.Entry(existingPhoneNumber).CurrentValues.SetValues();
```

Visual Studio complains that:

> EntityEntry does not contain a definition for 'CurrentValues'
>   etc...

I presume this means that this has not (yet?) been implemented for EF Core 1.0? Apart from manually updating the properties, is there any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have noticed, this API is not implemented yet in EF Core. See this work item: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1200

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I should have checked the open issues myself, but didn't think to look there.

Comment: FYI: It is now implemented.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I ran into this issue today, and it appears it still isn't implemented in EF Core. So I wrote an extension method to use in the meantime that will update any object's properties with the matching values of any other object.

```
public static class EFUpdateProperties
{
    public static TOrig UpdateProperties<TOrig, TDTO>(this TOrig original, TDTO dto)
    {
        var origProps = typeof(TOrig).GetProperties();
        var dtoProps = typeof(TDTO).GetProperties();

        foreach(PropertyInfo dtoProp in dtoProps)
        {
            origProps
                .Where(origProp => origProp.Name == dtoProp.Name)
                .Single()
                .SetMethod.Invoke(original, new Object[] 
                    { 
                    dtoProp.GetMethod.Invoke(dto, null) });                
                    }
                );                

        return original;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public async Task UpdateEntity(EditViewModel editDto)
    {
        // Get entry from context
        var entry = await _context.Items.Where(p => p.ID == editDto.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();                

        // Update properties
        entry.UpdateProperties(editDto);

        // Save Changes
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```