# Removing an item from a list doesn't remove from the saved object in Entity Framework/MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an entity that needed a list of type int. Due to this being an internal tool that only I would use, I didn't want to spend a lot of time making a UI/view to edit the list and I sort of cheated.

So, I have the following class:

myitem.cs

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    virtual public ICollection<Size> Sizes {get;set;}
```

size.cs

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
```

Between the controller and view controller, I did some funky bits. I had a single text field in the view controller called "Sizes" and I then split the input on a comma to an array, and assign the list to Sizes.

This works perfectly and as expected.

```
            string[] sizes = model.sizes.Split(',');
            myitem.size = new List<sizes>();

            foreach (string item in sizes)
            {
                myitem.size.Add( new sizes {Size=int.Parse(item)});
            }
```

In the edit one, I find the object, and create a new text string that basically gets all of them and this also works.

In the edit saving controller, no matter what I try, it seems to append. So, I basically did the following:

```
MyItem myitem = db.myitems.find(id);
...auto mapper stuff from viewmodel to model...
myitem.sizes=null;
...call same bits as create to split and add to sizes...
db.savechanges();
```

However, I am now finding that whatever I try to do in edit, it simply adds to the list in addition to what is already there - I can't seem to find a way to remove it.

I have tried many different things (instead of = null, foreach and remove(), and a few others) without much luck.

In the end, I don't think this is the best approach at all as I am going to end up dropping the items and recreating them by the thousands for the sake of saving a few minutes, so, I am going to create a DBSet for sizes and do an ajax interface to list/delete/add them separate to the main model. (If there is an easy way, please let me know?!)

However, the fact that this didn't work has annoyed me and I was wondering if anyone knows why?

Comment: Your edit saving controller code is not clear enough. Can you show full code what you are doing here?

Comment: did you try db.myitems.remove(myitem) and db.savechange()?

Comment: Instead of "db.myitems.find(id);" try "db.myitems.include(i => i.sizes).single(i => i.ID == id);" -- that will add the children to tracking.

Comment: @SteveGreene - I thought include was just about lazy loading if the objects were not there. All the objects are there already, and I can add... I just can't delete. Do you need include then to allow for tracking on objects defined as virtual? ... I'll try this shortly.

Comment: There are a few ways to attach the children to the context so they are tracked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968598/entity-4-1-updating-an-existing-parent-entity-with-new-child-entities/7969372#7969372