# .Net Entity Framework Update Detached Children

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So I have for example these models:

```
public class Account 
{
    public Guid ID {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("Profile")]
    public Guid? ProfileId {get;set;}
    public virtual Profile Profile {get;set;}
    ......
}

public class Profile
{
    public Guid ID {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("Account")]
    public Guid AccountId {get;set;}
    public virtual Account Account {get;set;}
}
```

Then I have a view (html) which request from a controller.

```
public class ExController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<Account> GetAccount(Guid id)
    {
        return await db.Accounts.Where(m => m.ID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

Then the html view edit / update the account entity, then pass it again to controller to be saved into database. If I just save from the raw passed entity from the view, the `Profile` will be treated as new entity. This is not what I want, I want the `Account` and `Account.Profile` to be updated, not added.

For example:

```
public async Task UpdateModel(Account model)
{
    db.Accounts.Attach(model);
    db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The child profile inside `model` will be treated as new entity.

How can I update the children entities as well?

---

### EDIT

So my purpose is not using entity as `view model`. I am developing an object mapper which map all properties from vm to model and vise versa.

Something like this:

```
vm.MapTo<Model>(ref existing);
```

The problem is EF always sees the children entity mapped from `view model` as new entities.

---

### EDIT

This is my mapping function

```
    public void MapTo<T>(ref T instance)
    {
        var fromProperties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        var toProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in fromProperties)
        {
            string propName = prop.Name;
            if (prop.CustomAttributes.Count() > 0)
            {
                MapToAttribute mapAttribute = (MapToAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(prop, typeof(MapToAttribute));
                AutoGeneratedAttribute autoGeneratedAttribute = (AutoGeneratedAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(prop, typeof(AutoGeneratedAttribute));

                if (mapAttribute != null)
                    propName = mapAttribute.MappedProperty;

                if (autoGeneratedAttribute != null)
                    propName = "";
            }
            PropertyInfo mappedProp = toProperties.Where(m => m.Name == propName).FirstOrDefault();

            if (mappedProp != null)
            {
                object value = prop.GetValue(this);
                if (value != null && value.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    DateTime dateValue = ((DateTime)(value)).ToUniversalTime();
                    mappedProp.SetValue(instance, dateValue);
                }
                else if (value != null && value.GetType() == typeof(DateTime?))
                {
                    DateTime? dateValue = ((DateTime?)(value)).Value.ToUniversalTime();
                    mappedProp.SetValue(instance, dateValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    mappedProp.SetValue(instance, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to re-attach all of those with `Attach` just like your `Account`.

Comment: But **you should stop what you're doing immediately** because **YOU SHOULD NOT USE EF ENTITY CLASSES AS VIEW-MODEL CLASSES!!** - it's almost as bad as SQL Injection because users can craft custom `<form>` submissions with arbitrary data and overwrite your FK keys, for example. I could edit the `AccountId` value in the `<form>` and edit someone else's Account! Always use dedicated and sanitized viewmodels and DTOs.

Comment: Another reason not to use EF Entity Classes as DTOs or View Models is because ASP.NET and Entity Framework use different Data Annotation attributes - or they reuse the same attributes but for different purposes (e.g. When EF `[Required]` it's to restrict SQL `NULL`s but not empty-strings, whereas ASP.NET uses `[Required]` to prevent empty-string values. And so on...

Comment: Hello @Dai, I am not using view model as entity. In my case, I am creating an object mapper from view model to model. I want to automate the variable assignment from vm to model. But the problem is when I assigning children entities, the EF sees the children as new entity every time.

Comment: "I am not using view model as entity." but **you are** using an entity class as a view-model because you're directly passing your `Account` object to the View and you're having ASP.NET perform Form Model Binding on it by using it as a controller action parameter. It's a terrible excuse that you think you're saving time because you're skipping writing a mapping (that's what `AutoMapper` is for) - you're introducing **massive security holes** to your project.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but please this is not what I am asking, you are off the track.

Comment: can you explain more what kind of `object mapper` you use? did you define mapping properly ? Are children loaded properly? Lazy loading will not work out of scope of dbcontext

Comment: I am developing my own object mapper, In debug, all the properties are mapped properly. Only when I called `SaveChanges` it throws error like this `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.ItemTypes'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ItemTypes'. The duplicate key value is (19e80f17-01bc-4980-a8a1-ea0619351334).
The statement has been terminated.`. EF is trying to insert the children as new entity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968598/entity-4-1-updating-an-existing-parent-entity-with-new-child-entities/7969372#7969372 

ef doesnt know that children are also updated just because parent is

Comment: You should set the Profile.Id values to their original values in the database.

Answer (score 0):

be careful with accepting model from UI. Its not good practice. This way you choose what is stored and also you can validate it.

query item again from db

```
public async Task UpdateModel(Account model)
{
    var dbItem = await db.Accounts.Include(x=>x.Profile).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == model.Id);

    //map values from model to dbItem 

    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```